# ANDROID. Отправить данные в базу через два RecyclerView и получить ответные данные в третий RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, android-fragment, recyclerview

Есть `fragment`, который содержит три `RecyclerView` (все три содержат `CardView`). Один Recycler отображает названия городов, а второй - типы топлива. Третий Recycler должен отображать заправочные станции и соответствующие цены для выбранного города и типа топлива.

Все данные хранятся в базе данных MySQL на сервере, а запрос записывается в файл PHP. У меня есть `adapter` для всех трех ресайклеров, и вопрос в том, как отправлять данные (название города и тип топлива), когда пользователь нажимает на соответствующий из первых двух ресайклеров, и получать данные обратно в третий ресайклер (с помощью POST). Я могу написать сам запрос, POST или GET, но мне интересует, как всё это работает вместе, и **в одном фрагменте**.

При необходимости выложу свой код (фрагмент, адаптер или что-нибудь другое, вам нужное).

Извините, если есть языковые ошибки, потому что русский не мой родной язык.

[Мой вопрос на английской версии сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829162/volley-post-request-from-two-recyclerviews-and-receiving-data-in-third-recyclerv)

Comment: Вы не написали самого главного: чего вы от нас-то хотите? Всё вроде просто: обработал клик->послал запрос->получил ответ->обновил список. В чём у вас затруднения?

Comment: @woesss, извините, но я не знал что надо написать ```notifyDataSetChanged()``` в адаптере, и при любой попытки, либо появлялась ошибка, либо список не обновлялся. Поэтому и задал такой неконкретный, общий вопрос. Теперь всё в порядке.